# Python 2.7: Traceback Error while creating dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, collections

Every time I try to start a script, a former colleague of mine wrote, I get a traceback error. It seems to me that the error is somehow caused by my machine, because the script works fine on other machines.
This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "T:\55-Test-Bench\Simulation\replace_productfiles.py", line 328, in
>   
>       init_dicts(hersteller, bereich)    File "T:\55-Test-Bench\Simulation\replace_productfiles.py", line 161, in
>   init_dicts
>       cat_dict = dict_builder(ws, 0, 1)    File "T:\55-Test-Bench\Simulation\replace_productfiles.py", line 74, in
>   dict_builder
>       for cellObj in ws.columns[n]: TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I'm really desperate guys, please help me.

Kind regards,
Frame

Comment: it would be better if you posted the code that is raising that error so others can review it and assist you in solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem by downgrading the openpyxl module (from 2.4.7 to 1.5.4), because my former colleague that wrote the code did that with the 1.5.4 version.